# Errors when starting node server in appium

Tags: android, appium

I was wondering if anyone had ever used appium and encountered the errors below. And what they mean? I've installed Appium and fired it up. I've already got eclipse set up and the paths to android. Just wondering if these messages actually matter at this stage?

```
> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app  --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
> usage: main.js [-h] [-v] [--shell]
>                [--localizable-strings-dir LOCALIZABLESTRINGSDIR] [--app APP]
>                [--ipa IPA] [-U UDID] [-a ADDRESS] [-p PORT]
>                [-ca CALLBACKADDRESS] [-cp CALLBACKPORT] [-bp BOOTSTRAPPORT]
>                [-k] [-r BACKENDRETRIES] [--session-override] [--full-reset]
> main.js: error: argument "--app": Expected one argument. null
>                [--log-level {info,info:debug,info:info,info:warn,info:error,warn,warn:debug,warn:info,warn:warn,warn:error,error,error:debug,error:info,error:warn,error:error,debug,debug:debug,debug:info,debug:warn,debug:error}]
>                [--log-timestamp] [--local-timezone] [--log-no-colors]
>                [-G WEBHOOK] [--native-instruments-lib]
>                [--app-pkg ANDROIDPACKAGE] [--app-activity ANDROIDACTIVITY]
>                [--app-wait-package ANDROIDWAITPACKAGE]
>                [--app-wait-activity ANDROIDWAITACTIVITY]
>                [--android-coverage ANDROIDCOVERAGE] [--avd AVD]
>                [--avd-args AVDARGS]
>                [--device-ready-timeout ANDROIDDEVICEREADYTIMEOUT] [--safari]
>                [--device-name DEVICENAME] [--platform-name PLATFORMNAME]
>                [--platform-version PLATFORMVERSION]
>                [--automation-name AUTOMATIONNAME] [--browser-name BROWSERNAME]
>                [--default-device] [--force-iphone] [--force-ipad]
>                [--language LANGUAGE] [--locale LOCALE]
>                [--calendar-format CALENDARFORMAT] [--orientation ORIENTATION]
>                [--tracetemplate AUTOMATIONTRACETEMPLATEPATH]
>                [--instruments INSTRUMENTSPATH] [--show-sim-log]
>                [--show-ios-log] [--nodeconfig NODECONFIG] [-ra ROBOTADDRESS]
>                [-rp ROBOTPORT] [--selendroid-port SELENDROIDPORT]
>                [--chromedriver-port CHROMEDRIVERPORT]
>                [--chromedriver-executable CHROMEDRIVEREXECUTABLE]
>                [--use-keystore] [--keystore-path KEYSTOREPATH]
>                [--keystore-password KEYSTOREPASSWORD] [--key-alias KEYALIAS]
>                [--key-password KEYPASSWORD] [--show-config] [--no-perms-check]
>                [--command-timeout DEFAULTCOMMANDTIMEOUT] [--keep-keychains]
>                [--strict-caps] [--isolate-sim-device] [--tmp TMPDIR]
>                [--trace-dir TRACEDIR] [--intent-action INTENTACTION]
>                [--intent-category INTENTCATEGORY] [--intent-flags INTENTFLAGS]
>                [--intent-args OPTIONALINTENTARGUMENTS]
>                [--dont-stop-app-on-reset] [--debug-log-spacing]
>                [--suppress-adb-kill-server] [--async-trace]
>                
> 
> 
> Appium server process ended
```

Comment: What are the arguments you are launching the Appium node with?

Comment: I spoke to one of our devs who spotted that error. Im not launching any arguments at the moment. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to start the appium server , do not need to specify apk path. 
Uncheck 'Application Path' checkbox from Appium Android Setting.

Desired capabilities need to be set after server start up from java code to start a new session. There you provide apk path and app capabilities.

Note : You can skip --bp parameter. It's not requreired.

Comment: Boom nice one. No more error messages I used selendroid in this instance and it's fired up with no errors so thats progress. Cheers

Comment: @Peter Cheers to that ;) . By the way with latest appium 1.4.16.1 version, you don't need to provide package, launcher activity, Appium will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `--app` argument has no value - there should be path to the `.apk` file.
And I think the `-bp` (Bootstrap Port) argument is missing.

Seems that should work with these fixes.

Comment: Hi, I've added an apk to it now I just need to add an argument. What is an argument?

Comment: `-bp` - it is also mentioned in your stack-trace.